How to Capture and Attach Buyer's procurement system Auth Token for Cart Return in Punch-Out Integration?
I'm working on a punch-out integration between a buyer's procurement system and a supplier's web app. The flow is as follows:
1.The buyer sends a setup request to the supplier.
2.The supplier responds with a URL, and the buyer is redirected from their procurement system to the supplier's web app (web catalog).
3.The buyer shops on the supplier's web app.
4.When the cart is ready, the buyer returns the cart to their procurement system.
The challenge I'm facing is with the authentication token to return back to the buyer's procurement system. It uses an auth token for authentication, but this token is not passed to the supplier's system. Apparently, it needs to be captured and attached to the return request when the buyer returns the cart to their procurement system.
Here's what I need to achieve:
•Capture the auth token when the buyer is redirected to the supplier's web app.
•Store the auth token securely on the client side.
•Attach the auth token to the return request when the buyer returns the cart to the procurement system.
How can I capture this auth token since it is coming from the different domain.
Also what would be a good practice to handle this scenario securely?
Thank you!
I was expecting this token will be attached automatically when sending retuning cart request to buyer's procurement system, but it didn't work.
